# Is there a way to diff two files, and move common lines to a third file?

Tags: python, grep, diff

My case is fairly simple in theory. As a refactoring task, I have two python files consisting purely of variables, each referring to a testing environment's own version. These files are thousands of lines long, but there is only a handful (<100) of variables in each file that are version specific, the rest could be moved to a common variables file.

So I am hoping in my case, to diff two files (version_1_vars.py and version_2_vars.py), extract any lines that are an exact match regardless of order, and move them to a common_vars.py, remove them from the original.

Here is my snippet:

```
version_1_vars.py

var_1 = "Stackoverflow is cool"
var_2 = "something_else"
var_A = "I am here"
var_version1_unique = "this is unique to version 1"
```

---

```
version_2_vars.py

var_1 = "Stackoverflow is cool"
var_A = "I am here"
var_2 = "something_else"
var_version2_unique = "this is unique to version two"
```

---

Desired result:

```
version_1_vars.py

var_version1_unique = "this is unique to version 1"
```

---

```
version_2_vars.py

var_version2_unique = "this is unique to version two"
```

---

```
common_vars.py

var_1 = "Stackoverflow is cool"
var_2 = "something_else"
var_A = "I am here"
```

I have tried something with grep and comm commands but while grep did move lines to a new file, the results contained both unique and not unique lines and did not delete any of the original lines. I also have some placeholders {} in the files so using purely grep -vf returns a regex error. (invalid content of {})

`grep -F -vf file_1 file_2 >> file_3` did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "difflib" library and then use unified_diff() to compare and find out difference.